# Invalid RSS Feed. Undefined item element: media:backLinks

Tags: xml, xml-validation, rss2

When I run my rss http://www.goalscout.com/static/rss2.xml through http://validator.w3.org/feed/ I get the error message

*This feed does not validate.*

```
line 14, column 9: Undefined item element: media:backLinks (2 occurrences) [help]

<media:backLinks>
```

So I'm unable to understand what's wrong with this xml.

XML namespace for `media` it seems be correctly defined, as [RSS Advisory Board](http://www.rssboard.org/media-rss) reccomends, I had googled around for few hours but no one had same problem.

Thanks to anyone who can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rss feed contains additional elements within the item element.
These additional elements are in the namespace http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/, but the validator does not have any schema information for this namespace.

```
<media:backLinks>
```

This should be OK as the RSS schema says that the validation on unknown elements should be 'lax' which means only validate them if you know what they are.

However the validator you are using seems a little over zealous, and is flagging these as errors, they should be warnings at most.

To my eye the rss feed looks valid.

[image]